# PHP Classes Can i use B extend A class in C class?

Tags: php, oop

Please check the example can I use the A function in C like the below example? If not then how can I use the A function in C?

```
class A {
    public function a()
    {
       return 'hello';
    }
}
class B extends A {
    //
}
class C extends B {
    // Can I use the A function in C?
}
```

Comment: it will take less time to try it than writing this question, yes you can

Comment: How can i use it in C? any example please?

Comment: `$c = new C(); $c->a();`

Comment: class C extends B { // if i want it like this? Then how? $this->a(); }

Comment: you need to define new method in `C` and inside of this method you can call `$this->a();`

Comment: i also need to define it in __construct?

Comment: you can call it inside of any method, and constructor is just method, so yes - you can define constructor and call function inside of it

Comment: can you help me with the method, please how to define it?

Comment: Classes form a hierarchy. Inheritance is transitive, so C inherits everything from B and A.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_objects.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods are inherited through any number of nested classes.

```
class A {
    public function a()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
class B extends A {
    //
}
class C extends B {
    function c() {
        echo $this->a();
    }
}

$x = new C();
$x->c(); // This will print `Hello`.
echo $x->a(); // So will this.
```